# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable on Python

Tags: python, mysql, database

```
import MySQLdb
from datetime import datetime

ID_RFID=raw_input("Masukkan nomor: ")
time=datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print time

db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="rfid")
cursor=db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT ID_Pegawai, Nama_Pegawai, Jabatan FROM data_pegawai WHERE ID_RFID='%s'" %(ID_RFID))
data=cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    ID_Pegawai=str(row[0])
    Nama_Pegawai=str(row[1])
    Jabatan=str(row[2])

    strID_Pegawai=''.join(ID_Pegawai)
    strNama_Pegawai=''.join(Nama_Pegawai)

    print "ID Pegawai= " +ID_Pegawai
    print "Nama Pegawai= " +Nama_Pegawai
    print "Jabatan= " +Jabatan

    if time>'08:00:00':
        telat="INSERT INTO  presensi (ID_Pegawai, Nama_Pegawai, Jam_Masuk, Status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, 'Terlambat')" (strID_Pegawai, strNama_Pegawai, time)
        cur.execute(telat)
        print ("Status Anda= Anda Datang Terlambat")
    else:
        telat="INSERT INTO  presensi (ID_Pegawai, Nama_Pegawai, Jam_Masuk, Status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, 'On Time')" (strID_Pegawai, strNama_Pegawai, time)
        cur.execute(telat)
        print ("Status Anda= Anda Datang Tepat Waktu")
```

I have code in Python like that and when I ran that code, I found an error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
Would you like to help me fixing this error? I would appreciate it. :') thank you anw, and pardon me for my bad English.

Comment: `"Blah blah (%s, %s, %s, 'On Time')" (strID_Pegawai, strNama_Pegawai, time)` is **obviously** the cause of the error.

Comment: Try to narrow down what causes the error -- for your own good and for everyone else's!

Comment: `cur` where defined?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\manggildatabase", line 26, in <module>
    telat="INSERT INTO  presensi (ID_Pegawai, Nama_Pegawai, Jam_Masuk, Status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, 'Terlambat')" (strID_Pegawai, strNama_Pegawai, time)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

That was the error.

Comment: @cdarke please do not suggest this, formatting the string *directly* would make their code vulnerable

Comment: @vaultah: true, just answering the question.

Comment: @vaultah No sense in providing vulnerable solutions to problems even if one had best intentions :)

Answer (score 3):

You have two places where you are incorrectly trying to formating SQL string(s):

telat="INSERT INTO  presensi (ID_Pegawai, Nama_Pegawai, Jam_Masuk, Status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, 'Terlambat')" (strID_Pegawai, strNama_Pegawai, time)
    cur.execute(telat)

and:

```
telat="INSERT INTO  presensi (ID_Pegawai, Nama_Pegawai, Jam_Masuk, Status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, 'On Time')" (strID_Pegawai, strNama_Pegawai, time)
cur.execute(telat)
```

You are incorrectly trying to format your SQL string:

```
>>> s = "%s %s %s" ("foo", "bar", "baz")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What you probably meant was:

```
>>> s = "%s %s %s" % ("foo", "bar", "baz")
>>> s
'foo bar baz'
```

However to help prevent SQL Injection attacks on your application you **should** be doing:

```
telat="INSERT INTO  presensi (ID_Pegawai, Nama_Pegawai, Jam_Masuk, Status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'On Time')"
cur.execute(telat, strID_Pegawai, strNama_Pegawai, time)
```

See: [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html) and related SO question [Protecting against SQL injection in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950362/protecting-against-sql-injection-in-python)

*Despite the community downvoting of this question and "close votes" I feel obligated to provide this answer to help prevent Python web applications from being vulnerable to common attack vectors from poor tutelage."*

**DO NOT** use `"INSERT|SELECT|UPDATE|DELETE ... %s %s %s" % (...)` form!

Comment: @cdarke Thanks taken care of :) There are two places where the OP is incorrectly formatting SQL string(s) :)

Comment: I've changed them but there's an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\manggildatabase", line 31, in <module>
    cursor.execute(ontime, strID_Pegawai, strNama_Pegawai, time)
TypeError: execute() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)