# How send Datetime as parameter in SQL command on Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime

I have a sql command and just want to select some records with some conditions ( using python & db is Postres): 
So, my query is:

```
 current_date= datetime.now()

  tt = yield self.db.execute(self.db.execute('SELECT "Id", "RubricId", "IsRubric"  
     FROM whis2011."CoockieUserInterests"
     'WHERE "UserId" = %s AND "Date" = %s '
     % (Id, current_date))

result=tt.fetchall()[0]
```

Problem: when I want to pass datetime to field "Date" I got error:

```
syntax error at or near "00"
LINE 1: ...rests" WHERE "UserId" = 1 AND "Date" = 2016-10-05 00:22:07.3...
                                                         ^
```

All "Date" fields in db is like: 2016-09-25 00:00:00

Also, datatype of field "Date" in database is "timestamp without time zone".

it's my pool:

```
    application.db = momoko.Pool(
    dsn='dbname=xxxx user=xxxxx password=xxxxx host=xxxx port=5432',
    size=1,
    ioloop=ioloop,
)
```

How I can select "Date" with format like this in my db?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). You need to read this q/a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950362/protecting-against-sql-injection-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't state what module you are using to connect to postgresql.  Let's assume for the interim that it is `psycopg2`.

In that case, you use the following to pass parameters to a query:

```
current_date = datetime.now()

self.db.execute(
    'SELECT Id, RubricId, IsRubric '
    'FROM whis2011.CoockieUserInterests '
    'WHERE UserId = %s AND Date = %s',
     (Id, current_date))
```

Note we are **not** using the `%` interpolation operator on the sql string here.  Instead we are using `%s` to mark sql parameters and then passing them separately to [`cursor.execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15)

If you are using a different package to connect to Postgres then it may mark parameters in a different manner.  Check the documentation or the modules [`paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) for details.

Comment: I'm using "momoko", I don't have curser!

Comment: Surely even a cursory read of the documentation would have told you that `momoko` is a wrapper around `psycopg2`, and that a [`connection.execute`](http://momoko.61924.nl/en/latest/api.html#momoko.Connection.execute)  method takes parameters just like a `cursor.execute` does?

Comment: I changed but still error, I updated code with my connection pool maybe it's useful to see what happened in my code!

Comment: You get the same error? Your original error is because you did not enclose quotes. But this parameterized answer does not need quotes. Please advise.