# How to build SQL Select statement with columns specified by user?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to select columns by name specified by user, but I want to avoid SQL Injection.

I think something like that isn't a good idea:

```
column_one = input("Column one")
column_two = input("Column two")
column_three = input("Column three")
sql.execute("Select {}, {}, {} from table;".format(column_one, column_two, column_three))
```

I can use something like that:

```
con = sql.connect("example.sqlite3")

select = "select ? from table;" 

t = ('id', ) 

cur = con.cursor() 
cur.execute(selec, t) 
rows = cur.fetchall() 
con.commit() 
con.close() 

for row in rows: 
    for cell in row: 
        print(cell)
```

What I get is: id id id id id id id...

Comment: This isn't a good idea because user can input something like that:
    "; Drop table;"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protecting against SQL injection in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950362/protecting-against-sql-injection-in-python)

Comment: Ok. But when I do something like that:
`   
con = sql.connect("example.sqlite3")

    select = "select ? from data;"

    cur = con.cursor()
    t = ('id', )
    cur.execute(selec, t)

    rows = cur.fetchall()
    con.commit()
    con.close()

    for row in rows:
        for cell in row:
            print(cell)
`

What I get is:

id
id
id
id
id
id
id...

Answer (score 0):

Write a query to return all columns from the table, and then select which ones to return using conditional logic.