# Python SQL Injection safe

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7

Short question: I want to make my code safer but in this line it crashes:

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT device_name FROM device WHERE device_id = %s", self.device_id)
```

This is working fine, but not safe for injection attacks:

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT device_name FROM device WHERE device_id = " + str(self.device_id))
```

I have no idea, whats wrong in the first line.

```
[...] raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): Unknown error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protecting against SQL injection in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950362/protecting-against-sql-injection-in-python)

Comment: It should be `...execute('whatever %s', (param,))` not `...execute('whatever %s', param)`, i.e. `(param,)` not simply `param`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument must be a collection (tuple, list or dict) of parameters.

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT device_name FROM device WHERE device_id = %s", 
                    (self.device_id,))
```