# Convert python string array for SQL column names

Tags: python, sql, arrays, string, quotes

How to convert python array like `columns = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3']` 
for forming SQL statement like

`"Select column1, column2, column3 from table"` ?

I can use join on array but don't know how to get rid of quotes of string.

Comment: The quotes are not part of the string. They are a display aid.

Comment: The quotes are not the issue. You can't parameterize column names. You'll need to `format` them in. If this is front-facing, you'll need to check the user input against a list of valid names to prevent SQL injection

Comment: thank you @timgeb join works just fine. did not realize they are just display aid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> 'select ' + ', '.join([c for c in columns]) + ' from table'
'select column1, column2, column3 from table'
```

Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes somehow I believed join would not be sufficient but this works

Comment: @user1411335 remember that strings could contain sql injections when hacking together sql statements like this. It's better to use a robust library. You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950362/protecting-against-sql-injection-in-python).

Comment: @timgeb, no library will make the above secure, "robust" or no.  Parameterized queries parameterize only data, not table or column names.  Most SQL client libraries are similarly restricted.  I suggest your caveat is misplaced because there's no data involved, no suggestion that the names come from the user, and that it's common programming practice for applications to have DBMS names hard-coded in them.

Comment: @JamesK.Lowden you clearly know more about this stuff than me, so I suggest that people listen to you on this matter.