# Issues with IF statements and Pypyodbc

Tags: python, if-statement, ms-access, pypyodbc

I am brand new to Python and know very little. I have connected my MS-Access file to my python using Pypyodbc. I am attempting to query with it using a user input however, I need it to be able to change based on the input of the user rather than having lots of hard-coded options. Here is the code and any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Side note**: I would be adding more options to this if statement in the future (a total of 5 accepted user inputs)

```py
import pypyodbc

conn = pypyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\DB\FILM_SMITH.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

input("What would you like to search for? ")
if input == "genre":
    genre = input("Please input the required genre: ")
    connstring = "select * from Films where Genre = " + genre
if input == "rating":
    rating = input("Please input the required age rating: ")
    connstring = "select * from Films where BBFC = " + rating
else:
    print("Invalid Entry")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your code is prone to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should pass the parameter dynamically, instead of putting it inside the string. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950362/protecting-against-sql-injection-in-python) for example.

Now to your actual question. If you want to avoid some code repetition, you can make a list of possible fields. You *should* have a way to restrict the possible fields, otherwise the user might provide an invalid field. Here is an example:

```
available_fields = ['genre', 'rating', 'another_field']
fld = input('What field would you like to search for?')
assert fld in available_fields, 'Invalid field'
value = input('Please enter a value you want to search for: ')
query = f'select * from Films where {fld} = ?'
# Now run the query with *value* as a dynamic parameter
```

Your requirements might vary, so probably there is a better solution for your case. But that should help, I hope.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip at the top about injection attacks. I will give this a run now and see how it fairs for me. Thank you :)

Comment: Hello. I am running this code here and am getting a very large function error flag up any ideas why?                                                                                                      
available_fields = ['Genre', 'BBFC', 'Auteur']
fld = input('What field would you like to search for? ')
assert fld in available_fields, 'Invalid field'
value = input('Please enter a value you want to search for: ')
query = f'select * from Films where {fld} = ?'

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    #print (row)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it to prevent code duplication using a dictionary.

the dictionary is structured like this

```
"key_you_want_to_search":["Question_you_want_the_user_to_answer","Name_of_your_SQL,column"]
```

```
import pypyodbc

conn = pypyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\DB\FILM_SMITH.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

dictionary = {"genre": ["Please input the required genre: ", "Genre"],
              "rating": ["Please input the required age rating: ", "BBFC"]}

user_input = input("What would you like to search for? ")
if user_input in dictionary:

    temp = input(dictionary[user_input][0])
    connstring = f"select * from Films where {dictionary[user_input][1]} = {temp}"

else:
    print("Invalid Entry")

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Comment: Hello. When running the code I always get the "Invalid Entry" print. I am running every line of your code literally copy and pasted from your post so I am not sure what is breaking for me.

Comment: thanks, mate. When I run it now I get this error code                                    
      pypyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error')                                                                                                                     but It will proper;y register the input now so thank you for that. It just will not print the results now.